# For my family and I/myself

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Is it correct to say:

> I want to create a brighter future for my family and I.

Or is "I" supposed to be replaced by "myself"? Is there a better way to construct this sentence?

Comment: [Most people would much prefer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+me+and+my+family%2Cfor+my+family+and+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20me%20and%20my%20family%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20my%20family%20and%20I%3B%2Cc0) ***for me and my family*** over ***for my family and I***. Reflexive ***myself*** can be used in both, but it's a less common option. Note that ***for my family and I*** sounds very "starchy, formal", so that one is more likely to use the reflexive pronoun (but even there, straightforward ***I*** is more common).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I must admit that, to me, “for my family and I” is simply an error rather than ”formal.” But I recognize its distressing frequency by those attempting formality. Presumably, I shall be dead before it becomes formal.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: I kinda doubt she'll ever say it in public again now, but don't you at least have a soft spot for The Queen's ***My husband and I...*** ?

Comment: Most English natives will get this wrong 9 times out of 10,. or accidentally get it right & not know why. I honestly wouldn't worry too much about it. "My noun & me/my noun & I" is almost a class distinction rather than a grammatical one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "I want to create a better future for I" is surely grammatically incorrect. "But I want to create a better future for myself" is not only grammatical, but sounds natural and idiomatic, whereas "I want...a better future for me" - sort of serves the purpose, but unless I was seeking to stress "ME", I wouldn;t use it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure the Queen used "my husband and I" as an object clause, did she? If she did she wasn't speaking the Queen's English!

Comment: @WS2: *“They are also the eyes of my dear husband, Jacob” the queen informed them. ... I believe you two are somehow [**replicas of my husband and I**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22replicas+of+my+husband+and+I%22+%22queen%22) from another dimension.* But that's not The Queen queen - it's some lesser (uncapitalised) monarch who obviously only speaks "**a** queen's English" (english?), as opposed to yer actual **The Queen's** English!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically,

> for my family and I

is not grammatical. It seems to come from a mistaken fear that “me” is not grammatically proper when combined with “and.”

In fact, “me” is proper as the object of any verb or preposition.

> He cursed me.

> He cursed her.

Those are correct. For some illogical reason, people think that therefore

> He cursed her and I

must be correct. In fact, it is not correct.

> He cursed her and me.

You may replace “me” with myself, but it is usually reserved for emphasis.

> I want to provide for myself and my family

suggests that your primary interest is personally self-centered and your interest in your family is secondary.

**EDIT**: The original poster asked a follow-up question as a comment. This edit responds to that comment rather than the original question.

English grammar has so many nuances that it is easy to oversimplify, and I hope that I have not done so below.

The basic form of the first person, singular pronoun used as the object of a verb or preposition in grammatical English is “me,” not “myself.”

Using the basic objective form of a pronoun as the object of a verb or preposition is always good grammar except for one situation. That one situation is when the pronoun identifies the same person, thing, persons, or things that constitute the subject of the relevant clause.

> He taught me Latin

Correct

> He taught myself Latin

Incorrect

> I taught me Latin

Incorrect

> I taught myself Latin

Correct

Now this basic use of reflexive pronouns is supplemented by a second use as an intensifier.

> I myself am not going, but my wife and children are.

In this example, the reflexive pronoun is used to emphasize the distinction between what the speaker is doing and what the rest of the speaker’s family is doing. Here is another example of using a reflexive as an intensifier.

> She did it for me, for myself alone.

Now there are rare cases where both the reflexive and objective forms of the pronoun are proper, but in such cases the meaning may be slightly different. Such cases involve multiple pronouns, one of which refers back to the subject.

> I am trying to provide for me and my family

implies “me and my family” are a unit that is not the same as “I” and so does not suggest a priority for self over kin.

> I am trying to provide for myself and my family

implies that “me” and “my family” are distinct entities, one of which is the same as “I”, and so may suggest a priority of self over kin.

Comment: If I were to change where `myself` is in that sentence, would `I want to provide for her and myself` sound correct? Also, if `I` is not the subject of the sentence, which one of these is it correct to say `They shot her and (me/me myself/myself`?

Comment: I would go further and remove the "technically", and state categorically that "for my family and I" is *categorically* and *incontrovertibly* incorrect. We will of course get a tsunami of backlash from hypercorrecting blowhards whose understanding of English grammar stopped after learning "me and my friends went to the beach" is incorrect at age 7.

Comment: @PrimeMover I tend toward prescriptive grammar myself, but a purely descriptive grammar is not absurd. What you and I call ungrammatical is in fact quite frequent, and English has a long history of eliminating inflections. I simply choose not to invite disputes about descriptive and prescriptive grammar.

Comment: @JeffMorrow well, all very well and all that, but condoning such outrageously ignorant and self-importantly snobbish inconsistency makes me puke. YMMV but such linguistic vandalism is tantamount to spraying obscenities over the Mona Lisa with a spraycan.

Comment: @JOUA For a response to your comment, see edit to my answer.

Comment: @PrimeMover Rather than continue to hurl insults at me such as “outrageously ignorant and self-importantly snobbish,” you could alternatively just downvote my response.

Comment: @JeffMorrow wasn't you I was insulting, it was the subhumans who insist on using this appalling linguistic solecism and thinking it makes them sound better than they are. Of course, an educated person like you would never dream of using such bad language.

Comment: You wouldn't like ["My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner), then? But even though I accept that most people "don't like it", I think there's no doubt that it's "linguistically sound" (as per the top answer to that linked ELU question). So -1 for your first sentence, which I think should go no further than "non-idiomatic" or "non-standard", rather than "not grammatical".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you mistake my intent. Perhaps I was unclear. I have no grammatical objection to “my wife and I” when used as a subject. My answer was intended to be limited to “I’ being used as the object of a verb or preposition. In my prescriptive view, that is ungrammatical but not necessarily unidiomatic, at least in some circles (which I doubt you frequent).  I just knew I was going to get cross fire from somewhere.

Comment: I confess I have no idea whether "my wife and I" counts as a "subject" when it's being treated as a "single lexical unit" modified by the clitic / possessive apostrophe in the example I linked to. But I guess that's not necessarily relevant. We could just as well disagree on the "grammatical validity" of ***Me and him / Him and me / He and I / I and he** are brothers* (imho, all "grammatical", but many people don't approve of either/both of the first two, and *nobody* would approve the *last* one).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I skipped over the “My wife and I’s dinner.” It strikes me as ungrammatical due to failure of agreement, but I cannot cite  an authoritative source for that position. I’d prefer “My wife’s and my dinner,” but in practice I’d probably avoid either construction with something like “The dinner eaten by my wife and me.” Would you really find the sentence “The judge spoke fiercely to he and I” acceptable? I would not. Consequently, I do not find “The judge spoke fiercely to him and I” acceptable either. Pronouns when used as objects are not in the nominative case.

Comment: I'm essentially an oik, so whereas I don't go so far as to endorse "Me Tarzan, you Jane", I do favour ***me*** over ***I*** wherever I think I can get away with it. The thing about being an articulate "non-standard English" speaker is you get used to recognising that there are *many* constructions you might not like that are in fact perfectly grammatical. I'm not 100% sure of my ground on this one, but I believe *My wife and I’s dinner* is grammatical but non-idiomatic, whereas *My wife’s and my dinner* is ***not*** grammatically valid even though it's idiomatically acceptable to some people.